# Обновить Debian 9 до Debian 10

Tags: linux, debian, unix

Доброго времени дня и ночи.

Каким способом можно обновить Debian 9 до Debian 10 (не 11)?

Comment: https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.html

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку (как я сам её не мог найти?). А теперь подскажите, где там написано как обновится на Debian 10? Стандартные средства обновят с 9 до 11.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, если вы на этапе 4.3 пропишете репозитории конкретно для 10 (то есть buster), то и обновление будет именно до 10

Comment: Что же :) Благодарю вас за ответ, всё именно так.

Answer (score 0):

Всё есть в [инстркуции от 10 версии, глава 4 "Обновление с 9ой версии"](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.html).